# Keeping count within a recursion function

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables

The second recursion question. I need to assign unique ID's to values in a recursive function.

Think of a folder structure, where each folder can have items or other folders. But each of those need a unique 'id'.

I figured, since I can't use any global variables in my recursive functions in python, that I'd increment the id with each call. But I couldn't be more wrong. Think of the following situation.

> 1 - Folder
>
> > 2- Folder
> >
> > 3 - Item
> >
> > 4 - Item
>
> 2 - Folder

Because of the way the recursion works, the id gets assigned twice, and there'd be no way to check. How would I go and do this? (I'm using python. Whenever I have a variable 'uniqueid' that I increment I get the error:

> local variable 'uniqueid' referenced before assignment

)
My code: make_link_item just returns a string.

```
def build_xml(node,depth,itemid):
    #if 'Children' in node:
        #print colleges
    depth += 1
    for child in node['Children']:
        itemid += 1
        print ("  " * (depth - 1)) + "<item identifier=\"%s\" identifierref=\"%s\">" % (("itm" + ("%05d" % itemid)),("res" + ("%05d" % itemid)))
        print ("  " * depth) + "<title>%s</title>" % child['Name'].encode('utf-8')
        build_xml(child,depth,itemid)
        print ("  " * (depth - 1)) + "</item>"
    lectures = getlectures(node['Id'])
    if lectures:
        build_lectures(lectures,itemid,itemid)

def build_lectures(lectures,itemid,parentid):
    for x in range(len(lectures)):
        itemid += 1
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print "<item identifier=\"%s\" identifierref=\"%s\">" % (("itm" + ("%05d" % itemid)),("res" + ("%05d" % itemid)))
            print "<title>" + lectures[x].encode('utf-8') + "</title>"
            print "</item>"
        else:
            make_link_item(lectures[x-1].encode('utf-8'),lectures[x].encode('utf-8'),itemid,parentid)
```

Thanks,

Mats

Comment: Can you pass an reference to an container object the recursive call, which contains the nextId; this nextId is incremented in the recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I don't miss the question.

You could go with a `class Builder` that is the object for building xml arborescence. Your class has got a member `increment`, which you increment by one each time you meet a new item. This way, there are no two same IDs.

```
class Builder:

   def __init__(self):
        self.increment = 0

   #other methods you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using the help of a Counter() class within collections.

For some apparent reason:

```
counter = Counter()
```

Works fine, and I can increment it like this.

```
counter['id'] += 1
```

Even within my recursion loop. I don't know why, but I think it has to do with reference passing and value passing.

Answer (score 0):

You could have each build_xml call return the maximum identifier of its children. Then you can set the next node to that id + 1. Something like:

```
def build_xml(node,depth,itemid):
    depth += 1
    for child in node['Children']:
        itemid += 1
        print ("  " * (depth - 1)) + "<item identifier=\"%s\" identifierref=\"%s\">" % (("itm" + ("%05d" % itemid)),("res" + ("%05d" % itemid)))
        print ("  " * depth) + "<title>%s</title>" % child['Name'].encode('utf-8')
        itemid = build_xml(child,depth,itemid)
        print ("  " * (depth - 1)) + "</item>"
    lectures = getlectures(node['Id'])
    if lectures:
        build_lectures(lectures,itemid,itemid)
    return itemid
```